# Siman 32, Kitzur Shulchan Aruch: Untranslated

Tags: shulchan-aruch

I was looking through the Metsudah translation of the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch when I stumbled upon Siman 32. The entire Siman was written in Hebrew, with no English translation. As far as I can tell, there are no other simanim without translation.

What in this siman was so objectionable that the publishers decided not to have it translated?

Comment: It is all about eating guidelines to guard the health of the body. You can see a translation here: http://www.yonanewman.org/kizzur/kizzur32.html -- It is quite possible that it was left untranslated because we don't follow the advice given there anymore. -- You should check the introduction to the Metsudah translation, it will probably explain.

Comment: There is a wealth of resources for studying the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch at [www.kitzur365.org/resources](http://www.kitzur365.org/resources)

Answer (score 7):

[That siman](http://www.kitzur.net/main.php?siman=32) discusses laws regarding staying healthy according to Halacha. Many of these are based on the medication mentioned in the Gemara.

Due to the fact that nowadays cures don't work anymore [Tosfos Moed Katan 11a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=12&daf=11&format=text), one is forbidden to even try them, lest one think that just as the Rabbis were wrong here (which they're not, just nature changed), they're wrong everywhere else.

Therefore, R' Akiva Eiger says that one should not even study those subjects.

Source: http://www.koltorah.org/ravj/medicINgemara.htm

Comment: This is a poor summary of that article in that it doesn't clarify who (tosfot? Maharil? R Akiva Eiger?) said what and it omits the variant views on the matter (particularly those of the people who lived closest to redaction of the gemara and might best know about the intention of the amoraim as well as of local phenomenological shifts).